# Linq Dynamic ConnectionString Application Settings

Tags: linq, dynamic, connection-string

I want to read my connection strings from the Web.config or App.Config file. I attempted to follow the advice in another Stackoverflow post.

The suggestion was to:

1. Set Application Settings in the Linq to Sql DBML file to false. (Double-click on the Linq to Sql file to open it, right-click on white space in the designer surface, select Properties, expand Connection property. )
2. Set Connection to (None) in the Linq to SQL DBML file.
3. Add an OnCreated event method in the data context partial class to read the connection string from web.config or app.config.

When I make the above changes and attempt to compile my code I get:

Error   2   Expression of type 'Object' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.

The error occurs on the 2nd line below:

```
    Using DcObj = New HMR_LinqToSql_QuestionDataContext()
        Dim Query = From Q In DcObj.tblQuestions Select Q ' *** Error on this line

        Count = Query.Count()

        DcObj.tblQuestions.DeleteAllOnSubmit(Query)

        DcObj.SubmitChanges()

    End Using
```

The only way, I found, to clear the error is to set Application Settings to True and select a connection string entry in the Connection drop down list. If I revert to Application Settings = True that mean there is still connection strings in the Linq to Sql files.

Any ideas for a solution?

Ed